# Ionic Rerun app on same port

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, browser, port

I'm using following ionic cordova run command to run my app on specific port. Everything works fine until I stop it using Ctrl+C

```
    ionic cordova run browser -- --port=8100
```

Since --livereload doesn't work with Cordova plugin, to see changes I have to stop the run and execute it again. The problem is, second time I use this command, the app starts on different port. Not on the one I specified.

Any idea how to run it on same port more time? Do I have to stop it other way than Ctrl+C?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. When you stop the server with Ctrl-C then the process continues to run in the background. So next time you start it, then it will automatically take the next port available.

If you want to have it running on the same port again, **you need to find and kill the node process that runs the server first**.

Not sure if that is the easiest solution, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to resolve this by using this utility
https://github.com/xtrasimplicity/killport.git

By simple command like

```
killport 8100
```

I'm able to kill all running processes on the specific port and then rerun cordova on the same port again.
The only disadvantage is, that sometimes this also kills Chrome and all tabs, not only one process.